# how to customise plot title in spatstat

Tags: spatstat

How may I change the plot titles and subtitles when using plot command on linnet object. For example

```
library(spatstat)
first = runiflpp(10, as.linnet(chicago), nsim = 2)
plot(first)
```

This code above gives two realisations of a a point process and a plot with the plot command because we requested for nsim=2. But it plots the two realisations with plot title 'simulation 1' and 'simulation 2'.

How can I change the subplot titles for example from simulation 1 to experiment 1?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to change the names of the items in the list:

```
names(first) <- paste("experiment", 1:2)
```

Alternatively you can change the argument `main.panel` in `plot.solist` (see `?plot.solist` for all the options):

```
plot(first, main.panel = paste("experiment", 1:2))
```